# How to connect SQLiteOpenHelper class with MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have created 3 classes (1. MainActivity, DBhelper and Student class). I'm beginner, who use simple code and all the time I have problem to connect DBhelper class with MainActivity. I think that everything is ok, but after clicking "buttonAdd" I get a statement that "My App has stopped".
In the MainActivity I used only "loadStudents" and "addStudent"methods from DBhelper because I have problem even with those basic level.

Idea of app --> Adding new Students to the editText, deleting them etc. I know, better is to use scrollList but I just want to know how use SQLite for first.

**Student class** --> I use it in the "DBhelper class" and in the "MainActivity"

```
public class Student {

private int studentID;
private String studentName;

public Student(int id, String studentName) { //konstruktor
    this.studentID = id;
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public int getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}

public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}
}
```

**DBhelper class**

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "studentID";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "studentName";
//initialize the database

public DBhelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARYKEY,"
            + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " + ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addStudent(Student student) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, student.getStudentID());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, student.getStudentName());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public String loadStudents() {
    String result = "";
    String query = "Select*FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int result_0 = cursor.getInt(0);
        String result_1 = cursor.getString(1);
        result += String.valueOf(result_0) + " " + result_1 +
                System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}

public Student findStudent(int ID, String studentName) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE" + COLUMN_NAME + " 
= " + "'" + studentName + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Student student = new Student(ID, studentName);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        student.setStudentID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        student.setStudentName(cursor.getString(1));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        student = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return student;
}

public boolean deleteStudent(int ID, String studentName) {
    boolean result = false;
    String query = "Select*FROM" + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE" + COLUMN_ID + "= '" 
+ String.valueOf(ID) + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Student student = new Student(ID, studentName);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        student.setStudentID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {
            String.valueOf(student.getStudentID())
        });
        cursor.close();
        result = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}

public boolean updateStudent(int ID, String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_ID, ID);
    args.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + ID, null) > 0;
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonLoad;
Button buttonAdd;
Button buttonFind;
Button buttonDelete;
Button buttonUpdate;
TextView textViewStudents;
EditText editTextID;
EditText editTextName;
DBhelper myDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoad);
    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFind);
    buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    textViewStudents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStudents);
    editTextID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    myDB = new DBhelper(this);

    //load
    buttonLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textViewStudents.setText(myDB.loadStudents());
            editTextID.setText("");
            editTextName.setText("");
        }
    });

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(editTextID.getText().toString());
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            Student student = new Student(id, name);
            myDB.addStudent(student);
            editTextID.setText("");
            editTextName.setText("");
        }
    });
}
// Maybe it will be better to use the methos under the onCreate method but I 
//don't know what should I write as a paramether instead of "view" when I 
//will use this method in the onCreate
//    public void addStudent() {
//        DBhelper myDB = new DBhelper(this);
//        int id = Integer.parseInt(editTextID.getText().toString());
//        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
//        Student student = new Student(id, name);
//        myDB.addStudent(student);
//        editTextID.setText("");
//        editTextName.setText("");
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **`loadStudents`** method you have `String query = "Select*FROM " + TABLE_NAME;`
this will result in a syntax error as there are no spaces between SELECT and * and * and FROM.

This should be **`String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;`**

**You need to check your code for missing spaces as you have omitted a number.**

- a space between the column name and the type and also a space between  PRIMARY and KEY, thus the studentID will not be an alias of the **rowid** column and will thus be null instead of an auto-generated unique id. **This, if not fixed (it won't result in an error), would result in the find/delete/update/Students methods not working as expected.
- there is another space  missing here `TABLE_NAME + "WHERE"` before the **WHERE** keyword.
- the same initial error `Select*FROM` is replicated in the deleteStudent method.
- ***Note*** there may be other syntax errors, the above have only been spotted by a visual look at the code.

I'd suggest making all the amendments, then deleting the App's data or uninstalling the App or increasing the value assigned to DATABASE_VERSION and then rerunning the App.

You should also check the log after 'it's stopped working', it will detail the error encountered.

### Additional

The following is code that has been tested and also contains some suggestions, such as only using a student's id to locate a student.

The DBhelper.java class (note for convenience the class DBhelper2 has been used):-

```
public class DBhelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper { //<<<<<<<<<< Change DBhelper2 to DBhelper

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "studentID";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "studentName";    //initialize the database

    public DBhelper2(Context context) { //<<<<<<<<<< Change DBhelpe2 to DBhelper
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ID, student.getStudentID());
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, student.getStudentName());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED add student allowing ID to be auto generated
    //!!!NOTE!!! ideally long should be used for ID and thus should return long not int
    //              won't be an issue with a small number of Students
    public int addNewStudent(String studentName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME,studentName);
        return (int) db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }

    public String loadStudents() {
        String result = "";
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACES
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int result_0 = cursor.getInt(0);
            String result_1 = cursor.getString(1);
            result += String.valueOf(result_0) + " " + result_1 +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< Get all Students as an ArrayList of Student objects
    //<<<<<<<<<< Alternative to loadStudents
    public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents() {
        ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            result.add(
                    new Student(
                            csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)),
                            csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)
                            )
                    )
            );
        }
        csr.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    public Student findStudent(int ID, String studentName) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACES
                " = " + "'" + studentName + "'"; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED missing double quote
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Student student = new Student(ID, studentName);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst(); //<<<<<<<<<< NOT NEEDED as already at first
            student.setStudentID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            student.setStudentName(cursor.getString(1));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            student = null;
        }
        db.close();
        return student;
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< alternative get student just by id
    //          uses the convenience query method rather than rawQuery
    //          recommended to use COLUMN NAMES not column offsets
    public Student findStudent(int studentID) {
        Student result = null;
        String whereclause = COLUMN_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(studentID)};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            result = new Student(
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)
                    )
            );
        }
        csr.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }


    //      Deleting just by id (see findStudent above) could/should be implemented
    public boolean deleteStudent(int ID, String studentName) {
        boolean result = false;
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "= '" //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACES
                + String.valueOf(ID) + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Student student = new Student(ID, studentName);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            student.setStudentID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] {
                            String.valueOf(student.getStudentID())
                    });
            cursor.close();
            result = true;
        }
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    //      Updating just by id (see findStudent above) could/should be implemented
    public boolean updateStudent(int ID, String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(COLUMN_ID, ID);
        args.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + ID, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

- **Please refer to the comments in the above code**

### Testing

The following code, within an activity's `onCreate` method, was used for testing the above :-

```
    mDBStudents = new DBhelper2(this);

    //Delete all students for testing purposes only
    mDBStudents.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBhelper2.TABLE_NAME,null,null);

    // Load some data and test methods
    mDBStudents.addStudent(new Student(1,"Fred"));
    mDBStudents.addStudent(new Student(2,"Mary"));
    Log.d("STUDENTS",mDBStudents.loadStudents());
    Student a_student_found = mDBStudents.findStudent(1,"Fred");
    Log.d("STUDENTFOUND", a_student_found.getStudentName());
    mDBStudents.updateStudent(1,"Bert");
    a_student_found = mDBStudents.findStudent(1,"Bert");
    Log.d("STUDENtFOUND",a_student_found.getStudentName());
    mDBStudents.deleteStudent(2,"Mary");
    Log.d("STUDENTS",mDBStudents.loadStudents());

    //Test alternative suggested methods
    mDBStudents.addNewStudent("Harold");
    mDBStudents.addNewStudent("Susan");
    ArrayList<Student> all_students = mDBStudents.getAllStudents();
    boolean after_first_row = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Students are :-");
    for (Student s: mDBStudents.getAllStudents()) {
        sb.append("\n\t")
                .append("Student ID is ")
                .append(String.valueOf(s.getStudentID()))
                .append(" Student name is ")
                .append(s.getStudentName());
    }
    Log.d("STUDENTS",sb.toString());
    Student another = mDBStudents.findStudent(3);
    Log.d("STUDENT 3","Student with an ID of 3 is " + another.getStudentName());
```

### Results (in the log)

The following was the output to the log produced by the testing :-

```
2018-10-06 08:49:27.410 2382-2382/so52598847.so52598847 D/STUDENTS: 1 Fred
    2 Mary
2018-10-06 08:49:27.411 2382-2382/so52598847.so52598847 D/STUDENTFOUND: Fred
2018-10-06 08:49:27.418 2382-2382/so52598847.so52598847 D/STUDENtFOUND: Bert
2018-10-06 08:49:27.426 2382-2382/so52598847.so52598847 D/STUDENTS: 1 Bert
2018-10-06 08:49:27.444 2382-2382/so52598847.so52598847 D/STUDENTS: Students are :-
        Student ID is 1 Student name is Bert
        Student ID is 2 Student name is Harold
        Student ID is 3 Student name is Susan
2018-10-06 08:49:27.445 2382-2382/so52598847.so52598847 D/STUDENT 3: Student with an ID of 3 is Susan
```

The results are as expected. That is

1. Student Fred is added with an ID of 1
2. Student Mary is added with an ID of 2
3. Students Fred and Mary are listed.
4. Student 1 (Fred) is updated to have a name of Bert.
5. Student 1 (now Bert) is found
6. Student Bert is listed.
7. Student 2 (Mary) is deleted.
8. Students Harold and Susan are added (using alternative method i.e. **addNewStudent**).
9. All students are listed after being obtained by the alternative **getAllStudents** method.
10. Student 3 is retrieved by the alternative **findStudent** method (just by id, so name change (e.g. Fred to Bert) doesn't impact getting the student) and listed.

Comment: Amazing :) --->1. "addNewStudent method"- it returns "int" and because of that student's ID will be auto generated?  
--->2. BEGINNING OF "TESTING"  -----> mDBStudents.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBhelper.TABLE_NAME,null, null); --> Does "delete" method comed from SQLite Class library and it delete all datas?  
---> 3. Shoud I switch on the app all the time when I want to see Logs, or is there any other button for faster seeing logs?
---->4. Why should I change "updateStudent" method for only studentID paraether if I have to write the name on which I want to upload other one?

Comment: ---> 5 I added 2 Students first
final ArrayList<Student> myArrayList = mDBStudents.getAllStudents();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Students are :-");
        for (Student s: mDBStudents.getAllStudents()) {
            sb.append("\n\t")
                    .append(myArrayList.get(1));
        }
        Log.d("STUDENTS",sb.toString());

-----> I try to present names of Students in a ListView, using ArrayAdapter but it doesn't work so I returned to Log.d and I see only funny letters which we get when ex: we want to show "String" message but we write "int" and forget to parse it

Comment: Q1 **`column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`** is special (with or without) ***`AUTOINCREMENT`*** keyword, says that the column is an alias of the **rowid** column which is (if value isn't specified) an automatically generated unique identifier which is from 1 - 9223372036854775807 (should really be long not int). Thus can be used to uniquely identify a row and is generally the most efficient way (consider it the super primary key) to access rows. Check out [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: Q2 delete method, if no where clause is used, will delete all rows (update method also).

Comment: Q3 because when you use `ArrayList<Student>` the Adapter uses the Student's **toString** method, which, if not overridden, uses the default object **toString** method and returns to objects memory location/address.pointer as a String hence @???????? (@ folowed by funny number). Get around is to either a) override the Student's **toString** method or, b) use a custom **ArrayAdapter**, c) use a Cursor Adapter (SimpleCursorAdapter).

Comment: Q4 you needn't but as explained in response to Q1, ID is all that is needed to uniquely identify the student. So why ask for 2 means of identification? (rhetorical). Ooops just realised Q3 above should be Q5.

Comment: Q3 writing to the log is useful for debugging when you have an issue (or in the case above) a pretty simple way of showing data (wasn't going to complicate matters by adding a ListView to list data). You should, if you follow guidelines, remove all log writing when publishing the App.

Comment: Thanks! Really useful